# Sorting answers by votes with an accepted answer

Tags: support

The following two answers have more votes than the competing, accepted answers on their respective questions. However, sorting by votes..

[image]

... yields inconsistent results:

- [Answer A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5149263/621962): most votes, newer than accepted answer, **not** on top
- [Answer B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8716680/621962): most votes (including a generous bounty), older than accepted answer (community wiki having won another bounty), **on top**

If accepted answers are supposed to supersede all others, I wouldn't expect Answer B to be on top. So, do the following factors come into play when sorting by votes?

1. Answer age
2. Bounties awarded
3. Community Wiki status

If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The accepted answer was authored by the OP, and as such doesn't get the "automatically top answer" effect.